# Determine the lines of curvature of $z=xy$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have to find the lines of curvature of $z=xy$

I calculate  Weingarten Matrix as described below

$p_u = (1, 0, v),p_v=(0,1,u),\nu =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}(-v,-u,1)$

so, $E=1+v^2,F=uv,G=1+u^2$

and $p_{uu}=(0,0,0),p_{uv}=(0,0,1),p_{vv}=(0,0,0)$

so $L=0,M=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}},N=0$

so Weingarten Matrix $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1+v^2 & uv \\
uv & 1+u^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}} & 0\\
\end{array}
\right)
=\frac{1}{{(1+u^2+v^2)}^{3/2}}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-uv & 1+u^2\\
1+v^2 & -uv\\
\end{array}
\right)
$

and Eigenvector  $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}
$of $A$ is 
$
\frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}
\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$
and $
\frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$

so principal directions are

$
\alpha p_u+\beta p_v = \frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}\left(
-\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ v \end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\ 1 \\ u \end{pmatrix}
\right)=
\frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}
\begin{pmatrix} 
-\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}} \\ 1 \\ u-v\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}\end{pmatrix}
$

and

$
\alpha p_u+\beta p_v = \frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}\left(
\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ v \end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\ 1 \\ u \end{pmatrix}
\right)=
\frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}} \\ 1 \\ u+v\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}\end{pmatrix}
$

But I can't determine the lines of curvature. How can I determine the lines of curvature? Could you teach me?

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set this up as differential equation $dv/du = \dots$ for the lines of curvature. From the work you've done, you can easily determine the slope(s) back in the $uv$-plane. If you get stuck, look at pp. 49-50 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Oh、really! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have further questions, please ask me. Once you're satisfied, please accept the answer so that this question will go off the "unanswered" list :)